# Good Pairs in Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Hatcher’s book says that $ \left( \mathbb{D}^{n},\mathbb{S}^{n - 1} \right) $ is a good pair; that is, there exists an open neighborhood $ V $ of $ \mathbb{D}^{n} $ containing $ \mathbb{S}^{n - 1} $ that deformation retracts onto $ \mathbb{S}^{n - 1} $.

What is the open neighborhood $ V $ in this case? Is it an annulus (without its boundary, of course)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take $V=\{x\in D^n: \|x\|\not= 0\}$. Then $V$ is an open neighborhood of $S^{n-1}$ in $D^n$ that deformation retracts into $S^{n-1}$ (can you see why?).

Comment: My problem is with the fact that I can't see how $ S^{n-1} $ is contained in $V$ , where $V$ is open.

Comment: @Mia: $S^{n-1}=\{x\in D^n: \|x\|=1\}$.

Comment: Oh, so the closed punctured disk is open?

Comment: It certainly is open in the disk! Its complement is a point, which you'll agree it is closed.

Comment: @Mia: You're welcome! :) You should always make sure to say *where* a set is open. I believe you were confused by the fact that $V$ is not open *in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$*, a fact that is of no importance here.

Comment: Yeah exactly... lesson learned :)